# What is the right way to overload the plus operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I have set of classes:

```
class A 
{
public:
    A(B b) {//..}   
    A(C C) {//..}
    A(D D) {//..}

    A& operator+=(A const& ls) {//..}
    A operator+(A const& ls) const {//..}
}

class B
{
//....
}

class C
{
//....
}

class D
{
//....
}
```

I want to support the following operations:

```
1) A result = a1 + a2;
2) a1 += a2;
3) A result = b1 + a1; (and C, D classes instead of B)
4) A result = a1 + b1; (and C, D classes instead of B)
5) a1 += b1; (and C, D classes instead of B)
```

How to do in this case? I would not want to use `boost`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are missing is implicit conversion of `B`, `C` and `D` to `A` for the LHS of `operator+`. You can allow this by making the operator a non-member function. For example:

```
A operator+(A const& ls, A const& rs)
{
  A ret = ls;
  ret += rs;
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: maybe you know what problem is?
I do: `A result = char + a1;`.

I get the error: `Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "char __cdecl operator+(char const &,class A<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > const &)" (??H@YADABDABV?$A@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std_utils@@@Z) referenced in function _main`

Comment: @Denis Not enough information. You'd have to post an MCVE, possibly in a different question.